# $2$-norm distance between square roots of matrices

Tags: matrices, oa.operator-algebras, inequalities, operator-theory, matrix-analysis

Suppose two square real matrices $A$ and $B$ are close in the [Schatten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schatten_norm) 1-norm, i.e. $\|A-B\|_1=\varepsilon$. Can this be used to put a bound on the Schatten 2-norm distance between their square roots. Namely, is there something of the form 
$\|\sqrt{A}-\sqrt{B}\|_2\leq f(\varepsilon)$? It is important that $f(\varepsilon)$ be independent of the dimension of the matrices. One can assume that these are symmetric, positive definite matrices.

I have a proof for the above statement when $A$ and $B$ are taken to be simultaneously diagonal. However, I was wondering if there is a more general proof.

Comment: I'm curious: where and how did the question arise?

Comment: How do you make sense of $\sqrt{A}$ when $A$ is not symmetric $\ge 0$?

Comment: Would it be enough for your function $f$ to also depend on $\Vert A\Vert_1$ and $\Vert B\Vert_1$? That is, do you already know that the matrices A and B lie in some ball of fixed radius?

Comment: @YemonChoi It should be true as stated. I have an idea how to get it (though it'll take me some time to check the details) but, if indeed true, it should be a textbook stuff, so even if I'm not mistaken, I'll wait a bit before sharing my home-made computations in case somebody has a good reference.

Comment: @fedja Indeed, I have a vague feeling that I have seen something like this before, as a remark related to work on Holder/Lipschitz estimates for operator-valued functions

Comment: @DavidRoberts: This arose in a quantum information context, in trying to prove that trace distance between density matrices being small implies fidelity of their canonical purifications is large.

Comment: @fedja Thanks for the help. I found a reference where something equivalent to this is proved. Look at theorem 1 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.1197.pdf

Comment: PratikRath @fedja Indeed I am now extremely embarrassed for not recognising this result straightaway; not because I claim I could easily come up with the proof (unlike fedja) but because this result is mentioned and used a lot in areas related to my research. It is (assuming positivity etc as in YCor's edit) the _Powers-Stormer inequality_ c.f. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/198610/a-generalization-of-the-powers-stormer-inequality

Answer (score 13):

As you yourself discovered by finding a paper of Audenaert: an upper bound of the form you require is provided by the *Powers–Størmer inequality*:

> **Theorem** (Powers–Størmer, 1970, Lemma 4.1; [link](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1103842028)) Let $S$ and $T$ be positive Hilbert-Schmidt operators on a Hilbert space. Then $\Vert S - T \Vert_2^2 \leq \Vert S^2-T^2\Vert_1$, where $\Vert \quad\Vert_p$ denotes the Schatten $p$-norm.

The starting idea of the proof is to work in an ONB with respect to which $R=S-T$ is diagonal (which is possible by the spectral theorem for compact self-adjoint operators). One then observes that, putting $Q=S+T$, we have $S^2-T^2 = (RQ+QR)/2$ and then one exploits the fact that $Q\geq \pm R$.

More general inequalities are known, see the discussion in Section X.1 of Bhatia's Springer GTM book on *Matrix Analysis* (Springer GTM).

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the answer to your question, but I can give you the following:
$$\|\sqrt A-\sqrt B\|_\infty\le\sqrt{\|A-B\|_\infty\,}\,,$$
where the $\infty$-Schatten norm is nothing but the operator norm.

A proof for this claim can be found [here](https://dspace.library.uvic.ca/bitstream/handle/1828/1506/DM%20442%20IR.pdf?sequence=1).

Comment: Thanks. I had discovered this result here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1934184. Unfortunately, I really needed the Schatten 2-norm to prove the result I was interested in.